# Get content from 2 files and insert into 1 file

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

**Hello guys,**

I'm trying to insert content from the 2 files into 2 columns new final.txt

Their are only one column in each file

example:

import file1.txt

import file2.txt

export final.txt

```
$file1 = Get-Content .\test1.txt
$file2 = Get-Content .\test2.txt
foreach ($i in $file1){
   foreach($y in $file2){
      Write-Host "$i" +  Write-Host "$y"
   }
}
Out-File .\final.txt
```

Comment: a simple copy command should work `copy "test1.txt" + "test2.txt" "final.txt"`

Comment: @RanadipDutta That is a cmd,exe answer to append the filese one after the other, not side by side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use th following using arrays :

```
$file1 = Get-Content .\test1.txt
$file2 = Get-Content .\test2.txt
0..$($file1.Length-1) | % {add-Content -Value "$($file1[$_]), $($file2[$_])" -Path final.txt}
```

---

In the expression `a..b`,  `..` is the range operator that gives a collection of integer from `a` to `b` see [about_operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Operators).

Comment: Thank you very much , I have one more question. what does 0.. do? and why are the text so far apart ? I only need one space. You helped me alot thanks :)

Comment: I add the explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A variant of JPBlanc's solution, but

- creating a csv with file names as the headers
- iterating over the larger number of rows
- double quoting the columns and with a `,` as delimiter

---

```
$file1 = Get-Content .\test1.txt
$file2 = Get-Content .\test2.txt
$Final = '.\final.csv'
$MaxLines = ([math]::max($file1.Length,$file2.Length)-1)
Set-Content -Value "`"test1.txt`",`"test2.txt`"" -Path $Final
0..$MaxLines| 
  ForEach {add-Content -Value "`"$($file1[$_])`",`"$($file2[$_])`"" -Path $Final}
```

Sample output:

```
> cat .\final.csv
"test1.txt","test2.txt"
"one","two"
"three","four"
"","six"
```

---

```
> import-csv .\final.csv

test1.txt test2.txt
--------- ---------
one       two
three     four
          six
```

Answer (score 0):

merged version, because Lotpings has right to use max nb line

```
$file1 = Get-Content C:\temp\test1.txt
$file2 = Get-Content C:\temp\test2.txt
$MaxNbLines = ([math]::max($file1.Length,$file2.Length)-1)

0..$MaxNbLines | %{[pscustomobject]@{file1=$file1[$_];file2=$file2[$_]}} | export-csv "C:\temp\resul.csv" -NoType
```

Answer (score 0):

other solution

```
$file1="C:\temp\test1.txt"
$file2="C:\temp\test2.txt"
$Result="C:\temp\result.csv"

Select-String $file1, $file2 -pattern  "\b" | group LineNumber | 
    %{[pscustomobject]@{file1=$_.Group[0].Line;file2=$_.Group[1].Line}} | Export-Csv $Result -notype
```